# The project was not built due to "Could not delete ‘project’."

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

Firstly I take error given below:

[An exception has been caught while processing the refactoring 'Delete Source'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65624006/12100307)

After TFS cache is cleared, TFS server mapping is removed, .lock file in eclipse workspace .\metadata file is cleared, then TFS mapping is created, Get latest, Import is applied again and project can be deleted.After this, I pull project from TFS to my local path again in Problems view, error given below is taken:

> The project was not built due to "Could not delete ‘project’.". Fix
> the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it
> may be inconsistent

Is my mapping can be incorret( Should I checked "Recursive" while setting mapping path)?

Thanks friends!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This [Team Explorer Everywhere plugin](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketplace.eclipse.org%2Fcategory%2Ffree-tagging%2Ftfs&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C143ab0ce7b4240fcac9c08d8b5dd23c8%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637459308678692234%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=0HnKfnWv81CNfb9OKYq6BHI3m1PRtfu6bibrHFGNeho%3D&reserved=0) enables using Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) within Eclipse. And it is no longer maintained. It works on the operating system of your choice with Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) - 4.6 (Neon) as described [here](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprevious-versions%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fjava%2Fdownload-eclipse-plug-in%3Fview%3Dazure-devops&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C143ab0ce7b4240fcac9c08d8b5dd23c8%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637459308678702227%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=NC9c4bFtZbyDfPxjBS7YW33BYGQ29xsGjLVMV2a6Fuw%3D&reserved=0).

If you are still using this plugin, please follow this doc: [Importing Projects from Team Foundation Server](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprevious-versions%2Fvisualstudio%2Fvisual-studio-2013%2Fhh568707(v%3Dvs.120)&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C143ab0ce7b4240fcac9c08d8b5dd23c8%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637459308678702227%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=%2BU8kE7pq3f00RQQl91pDU4PXs6AwN7rbcY0SJNv2%2F78%3D&reserved=0) to import a project from the server to your Eclipse workspace rather than manually mapping and getting files. Manual mapping and getting is error-prone and can cause unpredictable behavior if you did not choose the correct mappings. Instead, importing can check compatibility issues and prevent Eclipse workspace problems.

In addition, for this particular eclipse issue: “*The project was not built due to “Could not delete ‘project’.”*”, it seems that it is because customer has the workspace in a dropbox sysncing  folder like this [thread](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F20311985%2Fthe-project-was-not-built-due-to-could-not-delete-project-bin-classes-com&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C143ab0ce7b4240fcac9c08d8b5dd23c8%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637459308678712221%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=ja47BAkbLvf3nnxuM18Xm7pveelu2HbWQiJvcFigJP8%3D&reserved=0) answered.

Comment: @Denisa If my answer helps, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could guide other community members who get the same issues, thanks.